# What did halfnorm() go?

Tags: r, version, distribution

I would like to generate a half normal distribution in R (just the values above my specified mean).

I have tried rhalfnorm() but R doesn't recognise this as a function, was this function only available in earlier versions of R? what function could I use instead?

Comment: `rhalfnorm` isn't is base R (and never was). I'd encourage you to use your favorite search engine for something like "r rhalfnorm". The first hit I got [was this](http://svitsrv25.epfl.ch/R-doc/library/fdrtool/html/halfnorm.html), which tells you (when you know what to look for) that it is in the `fdrtool` package, which you can load with `library(fdrtool)`. (See the "{fdrtool}" in the upper left of the link, or the "/library/fdrtool/" in the URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that with the `dtnorm`, `rtnorm`,`ptnorm`,`qtnorm` functions in base  R described here. You will need to supply the cutoff values both lower and upper (in this case the mean for the lower) to get what you want.

Here is a link to the vignette:
[tnorm vignette](http://svitsrv25.epfl.ch/R-doc/library/msm/html/tnorm.html)

Comment: Link-only answers (and I'd argue that this is more of a metaphor than an answer) , are deprecated in SO. There are further ironies that there is no vignette linked from that package Index and further that it's not a link to a "base R" package and even further it's a link to a severely outdated version of that package.

Comment: Thanks for the Strunk and White analysis....how would I give a solution when the asker did not give data? I gave what she asked for...a replacement to the defunct tool, which I tested (because it has been awhile since I used it) and it works. If you are just trolling to comment on language use, you can find better examples than vignette (and I would argue that you used the word metaphor wrong) I was trying to get Brooke headed in a direction...it is called help, what was asked for!

Comment: thanks bethany, that function looks like it would do the job perfectly. trouble is R doesn't seem to recognise it. I'm getting "Error: could not find function "rtnorm" "

Comment: @bethanyP; I didn't make the rules. In this case where you seem compelled to answer a low-quality question then you should provide some code that creates an example. Shouldn't be that hard. I would expect the requested  random number generation function to just take a single number, so supply one. The number 5 would be my choice.

Comment: Brooke...I was wrong about the base R. `install.packages('msm')` and it should be good to go.I have tested it and it works. Give it a try